# Displaying a graph/pie-graph in HTML/JS/VB Script

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I'd like to display a graph for the results of a survey, I'm pretty new at these languages so I'd prefer something short and simple.

Thanks!

Comment: Tried working with Flot without any success.

Comment: I posted a list of possible projects that could fit your needs. If you have specific issues you can post where/how you got stuck and maybe we can help..

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at

- [Plotkit](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/)
- [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
- [jQuery Visualize](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/)

Lists of similar projects

- http://www.splashnology.com/blog/javascripts/290.html

Answer (score 0):

Use chart controls such as "Microsoft Chart Controls", "Dundas" and ...